# Any elegant way of concatenating Pointcloud from multiple solid state Lidars?

Tags: ros, lidar, point-cloud

https://github.com/tomlogan501/pointcloud_merger

https://github.com/Atellas23/pointcloud_concatenate

I am attempting to combine data from 4 lidars (Front , back , left and right )

Tried a simple concatenation of the lidar data , taking into consideration the extrinsics of the lidars .
But the resulting lidar pointcloud is not having data similar to a traditional mechanical lidar , we see the scan lines overlapping .

This is causing issue with odometry https://github.com/cuge1995/SC-FLOAM , I am testing with FLOAM , and as FLOAM primarily works by extracting the Edge points and Planar surfaces , this kind of concatenated pointcloud is not doing too well .

Its eventually resulting in a crooked odometry which is not useful .

Kindly shed some light on an alternative approach .

Comment: If point clouds have the same frame ID, you can simply combine them as one. If frame IDs are different, transform them to a common frame ID first. For example, first [transformPointCloud](https://github.com/ravijo/multiple_kinect_baxter_calibration/blob/5b883da744799abbf78f400f40e142d8450a7c9d/src/merge_pc.cpp#L56-L104) converts point cloud using a known transfromation then [combinePointClouds](https://github.com/ravijo/multiple_kinect_baxter_calibration/blob/5b883da744799abbf78f400f40e142d8450a7c9d/src/merge_pc.cpp#L150-L182C1) copies all the data to make one point cloud.

Comment: Assuming you have correctly transformed the data points into a common coordinate frame, what do you mean by "scan lines overlapping"? Your definition of "scan line" is unclear (point clouds don't have "lines".)